# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter/property type

Tags: c#, wpf

I've seen various threads on this, but can't get my problem solved. I have two errors that say:

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter/property type 'TestingApp.KIL' is less accessible than method/property 'TestingApp.KILInputPopupWindow.KILInputPopupWindow(TestingApp.KIL)'/TestingApp.KILInputPopupWindow.EditedKIL'

```
namespace TestingApp
{
    public partial class KILInputPopupWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EditedKILProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EditedKIL", typeof(KIL), typeof(KILInputPopupWindow));
        public KIL EditedKIL
        {
            get { return (KIL)this.GetValue(EditedKILProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(EditedKILProperty, value); }
        }


        public KILInputPopupWindow(KIL editedKIL)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            EditedKIL = editedKIL;
        }


        private void Close_Popup(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;

            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What is the access specifier on your class `KIL`, I believe you haven't specified any and hence it is treated as `internal`, and thus the error, Make it public.

Comment: That was it. I didn't have the class file open for it and wasn't thinking. Thank you!